# cassandra - start accepting writes after nodetool drain

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Once we do 'nodetool drain', what can we do to make it start accepting writes again?

on node A I did nodetool drain.

On another node B, when I run nodetool repair, it says:

```
Cannot proceed on repair because a neighbor (/<ip-of-A>) is dead: session failed
```

any ideas what could be happening here?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Nodetool drain` is intended to be run before stopping a node. If you don't want to stop the node then you probably want to run some combination of the following commands (depending on what your goal is):

- `nodetool flush`
- `nodetool disablethrift`
- `nodetool disablegossip`
- `nodetool disablebinary`

Answer (score 0):

For restore the operation, it is enough to restart the cassandra service.

> sudo systemctl restart cassandra.service

Answer (score -1):

After executing nodetool drain, once the the status is DOWN & NORMAL, execute  <`nodetool removenodes UUID`> then based on replication factor proceed or nodetool repair.
By Replication Factor (RF), I mean the value you would have set for sync of your data on number of nodes.

Comment: don't do it! this has no relation to the original question...